# UTC time to Timezone depending on the country

Tags: android, android-timepicker

am using this code to get the timestamp in my app, am storing this in my server.

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MMM-yyyy");
timeenter =  dateFormatGmt.format(new Date());
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("utc"));
```

when the user view the report summary on app, on user side the stored utc time need to be converted into their timezone depending on their location.

is any simple way to get the offset time of android of their location like
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Date-Type/TimestamptoUTC.htm

Comment: It's called timezone, not GMT. GMT is one specific timezone (Greenwich Meridian Time). The Java timestamp is independent from the timezone (it is always UTC), so you don't need to do all that. I suggest you always store the time in UTC and later apply any timezone modification. Android will automatically convert it to current timezone when creating a `Date` with it. Also note that one country can have several timezones.

Answer (score 0):

It's called timezone, not GMT. GMT is one specific timezone (Greenwich Mean Time).

`Date` is timezone-agnostic (it doesn't store the timezone). You need to specify the timezone in the formatter. For example:

```
final Date curDate = new Date();
final String format = "HH:mm:ss dd-MMM-yyyy";

final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(dateFormatGmt.format(curDate));

final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatHK = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
dateFormatHK.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PNT"));
System.out.println(dateFormatHK.format(curDate));
```